# GDAL Plugin with a different version of GDAL aready built into QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, netcdf

My qgis windows version is 1.8.0 Lisboa and use the gdaltools in version1.9.2.

I want to use the plugin NetCDFBrowser, but this plugin need the gdal 1.10.

I install 1.10 stand-alone gdal found here `http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/` 
but i don't know how to make it works with qgis?